# drag and drop the rows in the same grid

Tags: java, jquery, struts2

I looking the drag and drop rows in same the table.Currently i used struts2 with jqGrid.Here one table to andother table is working.But in the same grid itself not possible.Please give suggestion what is best to use drag and drop row wise in the same grid in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have option to sortableRows="true" then we can move up and down using struts2-jquery-grid plugin.